# ViewPager like functionality in Xamarin IOS

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am developing an IOS app in Xamarin Visual studio. I want to add functionality like android viewpager in app. On swipe from left to right or right to left another activity should show.How can I implement like that in xamarian IOS.[image]

Comment: i Think this may help u 



https://github.com/zzz40500/AndroidSweetSheet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equivalent to the Android's ViewPager on iOS? Swipe/flip through pages of data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734995/equivalent-to-the-androids-viewpager-on-ios-swipe-flip-through-pages-of-data)